# JavaFX Tableview with lists in populated object

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I know how to populate a tableview in JavaFX with just normal data types or custom class inclung normal data types. However I am strugling with how to make a tableview when my class also contains lists. I am using Scene Builder for my view, thus my view files are in FXML.

Here is my class with the lists being **duePersons** and **owePersons**:

```
    public class OverviewTable {

    private SimpleStringProperty user = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private SimpleDoubleProperty income = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private SimpleDoubleProperty expenses = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private SimpleDoubleProperty generalTotal = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private ObservableList<Contributor> duePersons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ObservableList<Contributor> owePersons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public OverviewTable(String user){
        this.user.set(user);
    }

    public OverviewTable(String user, double income, double expenses) {
        this.user.set(user);
        this.income.set(income);
        this.expenses.set(expenses);
        this.generalTotal.set(income-expenses);;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty userProperty() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user.set(user);
    }

    public SimpleDoubleProperty incomeProperty() {
        return income;
    }

    public void setIncome(double income) {
        this.income.set(income);
    }

    public SimpleDoubleProperty expensesProperty() {
        return expenses;
    }

    public void setExpenses(double expenses) {
        this.expenses.set(expenses);
    }

    public void setGeneralTotal(){
        this.generalTotal.set(this.income.doubleValue() - this.expenses.doubleValue());
    }

    public SimpleDoubleProperty generalTotalProperty() {
        return generalTotal;
    }


    public List<Contributor> duePersonsProperty() {
        return duePersons;
    }

    public void setDuePersons(ObservableList<Contributor> duePersons) {
        this.duePersons = duePersons;
    }

    public List<Contributor> getOwePersons() {
        return owePersons;
    }

    public void setOwePersons(ObservableList<Contributor> owePersons) {
        this.owePersons = owePersons;
    }

    public void addDuePersons(Contributor contributor){
        this.duePersons.add(contributor);
    }

    public void addPersons(Contributor contributor){
        this.duePersons.add(contributor);
    }

}
```

Here is the Contributor class which also extends Person class which has only "name" and "pid" attributes.

```
public class Contributor extends Person{

private SimpleDoubleProperty amount = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

public Contributor(int pid, String name, Double sum) {
    super(pid, name);
    this.amount.set(sum);
}

public Contributor(String name, double amount) {
    super(name);
    this.amount.set(amount);

}

public SimpleDoubleProperty getSum() {
    return amount;
}

public void setSum(double sum) {
    this.amount.set(sum);
}

public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty(){
    return super.nameProperty();
}
```

Here is my Java FXML view controller:

```
public class OverviewController{

@FXML
private TableView<OverviewTable> tableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<OverviewTable, String> userColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<OverviewTable, Double> incomeColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<OverviewTable, Double> expensesColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<OverviewTable, Double> totalGeneralColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<OverviewTable, List<Contributor>> personDueColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> amountDueColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> totalDueColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> personOweColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> amountOwnColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> totalOweColumn;

public void initialize() {

    userColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("user"));
    incomeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("income"));
    expensesColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("expenses"));
    totalGeneralColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("generalTotal"));
    personDueColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("duePersons"));

    tableView.setItems(OverviewTabQueries.getUsers());


}
```

As you can see, some of the last columns are not even used yet, because I want to make it work first for one of the lists in the OverviewTable class, and then I will do it for the other.
In the above controller everything works fine for the first 4 columns, which use normal String/Double Properties, but when try to input hte List, it does not work. Just to note that I am getting my data from MySQL database on localhost, but it is working correctly so that isn't the problem.

So can anyone help me how to solve this problem? I have searched all around the web but couldn't find an example for tableview where the Object used in the tableview has one or more list attributes in it.

If someone is wondering, here is how the result should look like when the data is loaded(please forgive my Paint skills):
["Due Amount" and "Owe Amount" are the columns that should integrate the lists with the Person/User's name and amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SukNd.jpg)

Any advices would be helpful :)

Comment: to write the code , it takes time